# How to keep keys that exists on both types?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I would like to exclude all keys from `Model` if they aren't present in `Bar` and also exclude the keys I pass in as a second argument.

I also lose autocomplete for the second argument as `id` is present on both types but that's not a big issue at the moment.

In the below example I would like to keep the `id` from `Bar`

```
type Model = { id: string, x: string }
type Bar = { id: string, foo: string, badProp: string } 
export type Bazz<T, K extends keyof Omit<T, keyof Model>> = Omit<
  T,
  keyof Model | K
>

type FooBar = Bazz<Bar, 'badProp'>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing was missing from your implementation, you omit all keys of `Model` and instead you should omit only those not in `T`. Consider:

```
type Model = { id: string, x: string }
type Bar = { id: string, foo: string, badProp: string };

export type Bazz<T, K extends Exclude<keyof T, keyof Model>> = Omit<
  T,
  Exclude<keyof Model, keyof T> | K
>

type FooBar = Bazz<Bar, 'badProp'> 
// evaluated to { id: string; foo: string; }
```

The key difference is `Exclude<keyof Model, keyof T> | K`, so we Omit only those fields which are in `Model` but not in `T`

---

**BTW**. replaced `keyof Omit<T, keyof Model>` by `Exclude<keyof T, keyof Model>` as its the same thing, but for me is more clear to read.